# Finding natural frequency from vibration analyzer data

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, dft

I was asked to find the natural frequency from a waveshape obtained from vibration analyzer, and I performed an FFT and told that the peak represents the natural frequency. Now I am called as an imposter for proving a false procedure. If this is a false procedure, then what should be the correct approach?

[image]

[image]

This is a clearer version:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what peak you mean, I see at least three different peaks? Also, calling you an impostor because your analysis (possibly) being wrong isn't appropriate interaction, neither on a human-to-human level, nor professionally.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have added an image that has a clear vision of the peak.

Comment: Hm, ok, but if that 2.6 Hz is the "natural" frequency (what is "natural" specifically, in your context), where does your energy at 2.6 Hz come from?

Comment: It's structural vibration data recorded through a vibration analyzer. That's much I was told. The time-domain data is provided as an excel file.

Comment: yes, but "natural" means something to you, right? It doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: The data provider (a civil engineer) told me a structure naturally oscillates at a frequency (which he defined as natural frequency) and noise is added to that frequency. So I told him that the most dominant signal should be his natural frequency if I perform FFT. Other should be the noise.

Comment: And in some online sources, I found that vibration analyzer also creates oscillation so that when it matches that natural frequency, a resonance is formed. That's why the peak is the natural frequency. (The document called it peak picking method)

Comment: ah, cool! Thanks! So, I'd agree, there's seemingly a strong resonance where you marked it! But, again, what about the 2.3 Hz region? It seems like your system has multiple resonant frequencies!